# Creating multiple functions out of existing code

Tags: javascript, html, function

I got my code to work, but I need to create multiple functions out of it, and every time I create one it messes with the logic and throws off my table

I need to create these functions:

```
calculateTax(); , calculateShipping(); calculateGrandTotal();
```

Basically:

```
function calculateTax(subtotal, rate) {
    var tax = subtotal * rate;
}

function calculateShipping(subtotal, threshold) {
    shipping = 40;
    if (subtotal > 1000)
        threshold = 1000;
        shipping = 0;
}

function calculateGrandTotal(subtotal,tax,shipping) {
     var grandTotal = subtotal + tax + shipping;
}
```

and the outcome is suppose to be like this image:[image]

My code (working):

```
function calculateTotal(quantity, price) {

return quantity * price;

}

window.onload = () => {

var rate = 0.10;
var threshold = 1000;
var subtotal = 0;
var product_total = 0;
var subtotal = 0;


for (let i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {

subtotal += calculateTotal(quantities[i], prices[i]);

outputCartRow(filenames[i], titles[i], quantities[i], prices[i], calculateTotal(quantities[i], prices[i]));

}

var tax = subtotal * 0.10;

var shipping = 40;

if (subtotal > 1000)

shipping = 0;

var grandTotal = subtotal + tax + shipping;

document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML +=

`<tr class="totals">

<td colspan="4">Subtotal</td>

<td>$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}</td>

</tr>

<tr class="totals">

<td colspan="4">Tax</td>

<td>$${tax.toFixed(2)}</td>

</tr>

<tr class="totals">

<td colspan="4">Shipping</td>

<td>$${shipping.toFixed(2)}</td>

</tr>

<tr class="totals focus">

<td colspan="4">Grand Total</td>

<td>$${grandTotal.toFixed(2)}</td>

</tr>`;

}
```

But if I try doing this (using the tax function as an example)

```
var tax = calculateTax();


for (let i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {

subtotal += calculateTotal(quantities[i], prices[i]);

outputCartRow(filenames[i], titles[i], quantities[i], prices[i], calculateTotal(quantities[i], prices[i]));

}
function calculateTax(subtotal, rate){
    tax = subtotal * 0.10;
    var shipping = 40;
    if (subtotal > 1000)
    shipping = 0;
}
```

It gets rid of the bottom box with the subtotal, tax, shipping, and grand total
[image]

Not sure how to create those functions without it getting rid of the boxes.

Comment: Where are you using this: `var tax = calculateTax();`? Where is `filenames[]` defined? or `titles[i], quantities[i], prices[i],` defined`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the html code for each row to each function respectively, and call them in order for the bottom box to show properly.

```
function calculateTax(subtotal, rate){
    tax = subtotal * 0.10;
    var shipping = 40;
    if (subtotal > 1000)
    shipping = 0;
    document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML +=
    '<tr class="totals">

    <td colspan="4">Tax</td>

    <td>$${tax.toFixed(2)}</td>

    </tr>'
}
```